# Animating unknown number of elements with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

Let's say I have an `ul` containing a few `li` elements. Let's also say that I have an animation like this:

```
@keyframes fcolor {
    from {
        color: #123;
    }
    to {
        color: #456;
    }
}
```

Ignore actual colors, this is just a simple demo.

The animation is supposed (for the sake of this example pretend that the animation works properly) to change the text color of each `li` element.

Is there a way I could apply this animation sequentially to each `li` element with `N` ms of delay in between? I mean, is there a way to apply that animation to the first `li`, then wait, say, `30ms`, then apply the animation to the second `li`, wait another `30ms`, apply to the third one, etc...

All that **without** knowing the number of `li` elements.
Also, css-only. I know this could be done easily with javascript.

I will repeat, just in case. I don't know the number of `li` elements, so solutions like

```
ul:nth-child(1) {
    animation: fcolor 100ms ease 0ms;
}

ul:nth-child(2) {
    animation: fcolor 100ms ease 30ms;
}

ul:nth-child(3) {
    animation: fcolor 100ms ease 60ms;
}

...
```

aka, hardcoding values, is NOT what I'm asking for and I will downvote such answers.

Comment: No you can't do that without script. The closet CSS only is to add 100 nth-child and hope for the best :)

Comment: @LGSon That would be rubbish, at best.

Comment: adding a delay via javascript, looping over all the lists?

Comment: Of course :) ... just wanted to make sure _without knowing_ really was _without knowing_

Comment: Would a solution using script at page load (runned once) be ok?

Comment: @fcalderan LGSon No. No javascript.

Comment: Updated my answer with an idea

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that using CSS only (at least not today).

---

As a non javascript workaround, I can see one solution that could work, where you server side, using i.e. ASP or PHP, creating your element's like this

```
<ul>
  <li style="animation-delay: 0s;"> ... </li>
  <li style="animation-delay: 10s;"> ... </li>
  <li style="animation-delay: 20s;"> ... </li>
  <li style="animation-delay: 30s;"> ... </li>
  ....
</ul>
```

And then set up the rest of the animation settings in you CSS